# Magento 2 - Set the page layout dynamically based on admin configuration

Tags: layout, xml, magento2

I want to know how to set the page layout dynamically based on an extension's admin configuration values.

I found how to change the page layout in the layout xml file, http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_columns, but couldn't find to do it based on admin configuration values.

In magento 1.x, I can do it.

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="settings/category/page_layout" condition="one_column"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="settings/category/page_layout" condition="two_column_left"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="settings/category/page_layout" condition="two_column_right"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="settings/category/page_layout" condition="three_column"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

But in magento 2, I couldn't do it.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For magento 2 you have to do it using Helper and controller.

In Controller you have to write in
**Index.php**

```
<?php 
namespace MageArray\Blog\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $viewHelper;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \MageArray\Blog\Helper\Index\View $viewHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->viewHelper = $viewHelper;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $page = $this->resultPageFactory->create(false, ['isIsolated' => true]);
        $this->viewHelper->prepareAndRender($page, $this);
        return $page;
    }
}
```

In namespace MageArray\Blog\Controller\Index;

Here MageArray is my NameSpace, Blog is my Module Name, Index is My controller Ans Class Name "Index" Is My action.

Now Create Helper File as i have **View.php** Helper and put code as below.

```
<?php
namespace MageArray\Blog\Helper\Index;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page as ResultPage;
class View extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getStoreConfig($storePath){
        $StoreConfig =  $this->_scopeConfig->getValue($storePath, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        return $StoreConfig;
    }

    public function initProductLayout(ResultPage $resultPage,$layout_id)
    {
        $post_list_layout = $this->getStoreConfig($layout_id);
        $pageConfig = $resultPage->getConfig();
        $pageConfig->setPageLayout($post_list_layout);
        $update = $resultPage->getLayout()->getUpdate();
        $controllerClass = $this->_request->getFullActionName();
        return $this;
    }

    public function prepareAndRender(ResultPage $resultPage, $controller)
    {
        $this->initProductLayout($resultPage,'magearray/general/post_list_layout');
        return $this;
    }

}
```

make changes in namespace, module, helper and configPath names as per your requirements.

Comment: How can i change without using controller only from xml file Like in magento 1

Comment: How can I change the category page and product detail page layouts?

Answer (score 1):

We can use something like below in Magento2:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" ifconfig="contact/contact/enabled" name="contact-us-link" />
```

Let me know if its helpful!

Answer (score -1):

You can use "action" instruction with ifconfig like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="path/to/config">
                <argument name="text" translate="true" xsi:type="string">namespace::module/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

"Action" is deprecated for now. Hope magento developers will add this feature to other instructions in the future.