# Magento 2: Custom frontend route thinks its in the admin area

Tags: magento2

I am creating a custom route as an example. Here is the code;

In etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="foo" frontName="foo">
            <module name="[Vendor]_[ModuleName]" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

In Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[ModuleName]\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $page = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
        return $page;
    }
}
```

Now if I go to `/foo` I get a blank page, when I am expecting to at least see the site outline with an empty content area.

If I look at the source I see html but nothing in the body. The interesting thing are the classes on the body;

`class="foo-index-index page-layout-admin-1column"`

Now I expect to see `foo-index-index` but why would `page-layout-admin-1column` exist. I do not have a layout file for this handle.

Comment: Layout appears when you mention it in layout.xml file for your corresponding controller. Can you please post your layout file code of controller_index_index.xml ?

Comment: There is no layout file associated with the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following file at `/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/controller_index_index.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="3columns" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> 
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Notice `layout="3columns"` in above code. This will help display the site outline with an empty content area. More details here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_columns

In case you want to set default layout dynamically for your custom module, you might want to look at this post: [Magento 2 - Set the page layout dynamically based on admin configuration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85064/magento-2-set-the-page-layout-dynamically-based-on-admin-configuration)

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Creating the XML **does** work as you suggest. I wasn't aware that it was a requirement but after doing some digging it looks like if you do not specify a page layout it defaults to admin-1column. Doesn't seem like a sensible default to me but that is for another day.