# magento2: how to use config function in xml

Tags: magento2, module

I want to use config function in XML file to render the phtml file same as below that we use in magento 1.x.x

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="mymodule/general/enabled"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

How can I do it on magento2.

I have created my config function in helper and want to use these function to render the phtml, based on configuration setting.

Comment: check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85064/magento-2-set-the-page-layout-dynamically-based-on-admin-configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use something like below in Magento2:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" ifconfig="contact/contact/enabled" name="contact-us-link">
```

Let me know if its helpful!