# Magento 2 : Layout Xml

Tags: magento2, magento2.1.0

I created layout XML file for `2columns-left` layout.
I need to use two options `2columns-left` and `2columns-right` in system configuration.
When admin selects `2columns-right` it should set layout on Right side and vise versa.

How should i proceed?

[image]

Comment: Hello, Please help me for above question.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please use more words to make clear what you want to achieve, what did you do where and how, what happens and what you expected.

Comment: Refer :: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128725/magento-2-set-category-page-layout-dynamically
OR
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85064/magento-2-set-the-page-layout-dynamically-based-on-admin-configuration

Comment: Don't understand of your question .

Comment: Check my updated question fschmengler and Paarth.

Comment: @PayalPatel you need to tag their names to send them notification as how i did in this comment....

Comment: You will use $this->setTemplate function according to your current layout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are doing this for a page, I assume you have a controller action for that page.
You can do this in your controller action:

```
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Controller\[Something];

class SomeAction extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action 
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $scopeConfig;
    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
       \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
       \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function execute()
    {
         $page = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
         $layout = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                       'path/to/config_value', 
                       \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_STORE
         );
         if ($layout) {
             $page->getConfig()->setPageLayout($layout);
         }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the code, so watch out for typos.

Comment: Hello Marius, when i try above code, front page is blank. Why?

Comment: try enabling the error reporting and see what's wrong