# Magento 2 - Set Category page layout dynamically

Tags: magento2

I tried set dynamically category page layout base on admin configuration.
But I can't set it use `ifconfig`.

Can you please help me set the layout dynamically.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: plz show  your code for layout, which code have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any code, because I could't find the correct  syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There are several layout files available for the category page in Magento 2, the main files being located under `app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout` folder:

```
catalog_category_view.xml
catalog_category_view_type_default.xml //adds the left side navigation bar
catalog_category_view_type_default_without_children.xml //does not add the left side navigation bar
```